# Is there any way to inspect the view heirarchy in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm looking into doing some fancy animations on top of views created using SwiftUI.  With UIKit, it's possible to walk the view/subview heirarchy and for example look at the frame of each view.  Is there any similar capability in SwiftUI?

Comment: In SwiftUI there is no "view hierarchy" in the sense of UIKit

Comment: Well conceptually there is most certainly a view heirarchy no?  SwiftUI is built around the concept of views containing other views.

Comment: No, there is no "conceptually". You can think about "hierarchy" in code as "rendering order" (but even that can be changed by modifiers), however in runtime you have "flat" rendered context. So it is better not to think in that way at all (however, of course, there are exceptions, at least for now, say, in case of wrapped UIKit views).

Comment: Ok is there any way to get raw view data from the rendering context?